# How do I make a success redirect in htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hi I tried to make a redirect within .htaccess, but with no result.

This are my tries:

1. `RedirectMatch 301 www.magazinfermier.ro/index.php?route=product/category&path=35_49(.*) http://www.fermier.ro/profesionist/vinificatie/laborator//$1`

does not work

2. `Redirect 301 /index.php?route=product/category&path=35_49 http://www.fermier.ro/profesionist/vinificatie/laborator/`

does not work

What am i doing wrong ? thx in advance

This is the content of my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(magazinfermier\.ro)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.magazinfermier.ro/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=product/category&path=35_49
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /profesionist/vinificatie/laborator/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

and this is the old host :**magazinfermier.ro**  and this is new one: **fermier.ro**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot match query string using `RedirectMatch`. Use `mod_rewrite` instead in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=product/category&path=35_49
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /profesionist/vinificatie/laborator/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: @anubhava it still does not work, I updated my post to see all of the .htaccess code

Comment: @Croises i updated my post see all of the content of my htaccess file. What is wrong with it ? thx